Redis Methods showing HOT in Performance Monitoring
My IIS Server with DotNetFramework 4.8 uses Redis in:

Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider to share HttpSession in loadbalanced machines
Keeping internal cache data

Recently we did some updates in the packages as well as merged some older branches and it has started consuming 100% CPU on all the IIS machines. When checked through CPU Profilers(NewRelic), it shows internal methods of the Redis DLL as HOT.

Using these latest packages

Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis - v2.4.3
Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvide - v5.0.4

As these are already the latest available DLLs, what else should I try?

If you “merged some older branches” you should probably start by going backwards through your VCS history and find the change that introduced the error
